# adding already existing row to sqlite3 without getting exception

Tags: android, exception, sqlite, constraints

I got sqlite DB on my android app to save reservations.
The one of the tables there contains the header of each reservation that may contain several parts of the reservation, each reservation has RES_ID while each part has PART_ID
the main table contains only the RES_ID as primary key, i have other tables that contains the parts in each of them PART_ID and RES_ID are both primary keys

i have a case in which i insert several part objects into the DB so eventually what happens is i try to insert a two or more rows with the same RES_ID to the table.
naturally i get SQLiteException, constrains violation since there's already a row with that primary key.

Is there an SQL statement or a java method\const that will notify SQLite that failing is ok and i don
't want the exception ? (just for that table)

Comment: When I get your question right, you are looking for insert or replace. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

Comment: i already do an insert, but since i have two objects with the same RES_ID i get an exception for constrains violation. if  i'll use an update but the row does not exists still i'll get another exception , as far as i know.

Comment: So use insert or replace and it replaces an already existing row or inserts it, if it is not present...

Comment: ther idea was to avoid an extra query... i can always make a query and avoid an insert uppon one or more rows in the query, but that's extra time taker which i was trying to avoid.

Comment: Using the `replace()` method does not require an extra query - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: right u are :-) replace does not throws an exception in sqlite if the row doesn't exists and replace the data in case it does.
can you form your comment to an answer i can accept or shell i for a question ? (then i have to wait 24 hours to accept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get your question right, you are looking for `insert or replace`. [Click](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html)

`replace` is a shortcut for this.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this work :

INSERT ((SELECT v1 AS c1, v2 AS c2, ... , vn AS cn) EXCEPT tablename) INTO tablename;

?

Or similar :

INSERT ((SELECT v1 AS c1, v2 AS c2, ... , vn AS cn) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE pkc1 = pkv1 AND pkc2 = pkv2 AND ... AND pkcj =pkvj)) INTO tablename;

?

Answer (score -1):

There might be another way but indeed using replace instead of INSERT would do the job nicely.
Checking with the sqlite3 console client i was able to insert a non existing row into the talked about table. If the row already exists, the values will be updated anyway.

10x Jeff and janoliver!